# what kind of epoch time is this

Tags: python, time, epoch

i have an epoch time value as : `1412835422648`

When I convert it into date and time using python , I get a weird date. This is done as follows:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1412835422648))
'46740-12-22 07:04:08'
```

What kind of epoch time is that?

How can I get my local system time in a similar format using python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This timestamp is in *milliseconds* since the epoch. It possibly came from Java where this sort of timestamp is standard.

To make it usable with `time.localtime()`, just divide it by 1000 to convert to seconds:

```
In [2]: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1412835422648 / 1000))
Out[2]: '2014-10-09 07:17:02'
```

To get the time in this format, use `time.time()`, multiply the result by 1000 and round to an integer:

```
In [4]: int(time.time() * 1000 + 0.5)
Out[4]: 1412836344862L
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what does half of a millisecond change? Is it just to convert rounding from flooring to nearest `int` ?

Comment: That's exactly the purpose, yes.

Comment: if I may ask a corollary please, What's the best way of showing time difference between epoch times? Lets say I have an epoch_1 = `1412838135922` and epoch_2 = `1412838432028`. How can I display how long has it been between epoch1 and epoch2?

Comment: subtract one from another - and then use a timedelta to get a nice readable time.